# listile opacity problems flutter

Tags: flutter

I cannot figure out how to implement opacity so that it doesn't affect the text within it..... i just want the background to be completely gone and leave the text. i cant just leave it to white because the app itself has a background

and i also can't find documentation on how to create a line, spanning the screen, below to separate the tiles from eachother

here is my listile

```
? new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: controlHeadings.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return new Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.9,
                        child: new Card(
                          color: Theme.CompanyColors.coolGrey,
                          elevation: 2.0,
                          child: new ListTile(
                              leading: new Text(
                                "${controlHeadings[index]['id']}",
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              title: new Text(
                                "${controlHeadings[index]['title']}",
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                ),
                              ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider `Opacity` as a filter. It affects its child entirely. Taking this into consideration what you are asking for is "impossible".

Instead, you should extract the content that needs to bypass `Opacity` to make sure it is *not* as a child of `Opacity`.  You can achieve this by using a `Stack`:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: .9,
        child: Card(color: Colors.red),
      ),
    ),
    Text("Not affected"),
  ],
)
```

---

Alternatively, you can change the background color of your `Card` using `withOpacity` method:

```
Card(
  color: Colors.red.withOpacity(.9),
  child: Text("foo"),
)
```

Comment: for the first answer using stack, i need a listile as a child of card in order to list text in the card. i tried putting a new listtile where 'text ("not affected")' was to put the text in but that doesn't work.  and the second one just blanks out everything inside it as well.... i'm using listile to be able to list everything from the database using passed data and does that mean i have to figure out another way to do this?